# SSL on Amazon S3 as "static website"

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket on S3 that needs to utilize the "static website" functionality in order to take advantage of the routing rules capabilities.  Enabling this broke the built in ssl certificate.  Is there a built in mechanism for supporting SSL requests on the S3 bucket while using the static website hosting?  It seems like a major miss in functionality if this isn't present.

Also note that I need this to function outside of CloudFront as the hosted CSS suffers from CORS issues, which only the S3 bucket can resolve with its CORS Configuration options.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Static hosting and SSL do not work together.  You could, as you know, use the ssl wildcard cert on the REST endpoint, but then you lose routing rules.  And, as you have apparently found, Cloudfront's support for CORS is somewhat limited from what I can tell unless you have a very generous CORS policy.

From an AWS product manager on 2013-05-10:

> Thanks for all your feedback. S3 static website hosting currently does not support SSL certificates. We may consider adding this support in the future. Please keep your feedback coming!
>
> https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=60821#450167

The only noteworthy alternative that comes to mind -- which I have implemented successfully in the past -- is to use a reverse proxy (HAProxy? Nginx? Apache? Maybe even stunnel4? Others?) on EC2 in the same region to terminate the SSL and proxy the requests over to S3.  In the same region, there are no bandwidth charges between EC2 and S3 so the only cost is that of the instance... which could still end up being less than the cost of using Cloudfront, and should perform comparably (without the caching aspect, of course).